# How to define chart.js time scale date formats

Tags: angularjs, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

I am using chart.js and I want to set custom date formats for my data. How can I do that?

For example, here is my  x axis date config:

```
 scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time',
                        position: 'bottom',
                        time: {
                            displayFormats: {
                                **'day': 'Y M D',
                                'week': 'Y M D',
                                'month': 'Y M D',
                                'year': 'Y M D',**
                            }
                        },
```

How can I control the tooltip and axis tick label formats.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: on the graph there are points, when I hover each point I get the data that the point is "made of", for example : point (x: 02/05/2017, y: 70), when I see it on the graph I get the full date and not only 02/05/2017, I want to edit this data, how can I do that?

Comment: It still isn't very clear what exactly you are trying to do but my answer gives you examples of various options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to format the data tbat appears in the point hover tooltip, then when using a time scale, you can use the [`tooltipFormat`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-time-scale) property to set the moment js format string to use for the tooltip.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    position: 'bottom',
    time: {
      tooltipFormat: "MM-DD-YYYY",
    },
  }],
}
```

If however you are trying to set the format of the x axis tick labels so that it only shows the day portion of the date, then you can use the [`unit`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-time-units) property.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    position: 'bottom',
    time: {
      unit: "day",
    },
  }],
}
```

The above example uses the default display format defined for `day` which is 'll' (eg. Sep 4 1986).  If you want to change this format to something else (eg. 09/04/1986), then you can re-define the `day` display format like this.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    position: 'bottom',
    time: {
      unit: "day",
      displayFormats: {
        day: "l",
      },
    },
  }],
}
```

Comment: @Damkulul You can change your formats to whatever moment.js format you want, just refer to the available moment.js format options (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)